# Python Multiprocessing Schema For Dumping data through process1 and loading required amount by process 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I Like To Draw Your Attention Since I Am New To Multiprocessing coding

here is the problem
i have two process that i have to run on differnt cores using multiprocessing module

the first task has to collect data from sensors line by line and append it to memory(data structure:python list)
it is a serial connection(one by one data given)
i have already a working code for this
but since i have to  collect data for it till sensor is connected
for infinite time till code runs
the second process is to collect first 140 data from the data structure accesed above
and print in second process function for some other task
,br>
the pseduo code looks like

```
Buffer=[] #global list
def process1():
   Obj=port.open()
   a=read_data(Obj)
   Buffer.append(a)
   port.close()
retunrn Buffer

def process2(Buffer):
    print('hello from process2')
    if len(Buffer)>=140:
        print(Buffer)
        #do some task
    else:
        print(Buffer)

def interprocesscommunication()
   import multiprocessing
   while(True):
      p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=process1)
      p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=process2,args=(Buffer))
      p1.run()
      p2.run()
```

anyone has better schema of how to run both process for infinite time parallely on different core
Note: I am also in doubt about both process can share memory or not  if not how?

Comment: Why do you think the processes must run on different cores?

Comment: Regarding your first process... do you mean it runs forever even if no device is connected? Does it permanently store the acquired data somewhere else too?

Comment: Regarding your second process... do you mean it only needs to access the newest 140 samples? Or it should only start when there are 140 samples? Should it run once a second? Or once a minute? Or does it need to be told each time there's a new sample?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Beacuse it is demand to run on multicore as there is so many code involve by which real time latency can be disturb

Comment: @MarkSetchell it has to run forever till sensor is connected when it will not give data it will be break of

Comment: @MarkSetchell neweset samples

Comment: How to run a process for a infinite time? without while

Comment: This is still not making much sense. Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. The acquisition has to run forever until a sensor is connected? What does that mean? It must stop as soon as the sensor is connected and able to provide data? That doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Processes cannot share memory in this way.
You have to synchronize state in some way.
The most common approach is to use [multiprocessing.Pipe()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe)

Also, take a look on this example:

```
# example of using a duplex pipe between processes
from time import sleep
from random import random
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pipe
 
# generate and send a value
def generate_send(connection, value):
    # generate value
    new_value = random()
    # block
    sleep(new_value)
    # update value
    value = value + new_value
    # report
    print(f'>sending {value}', flush=True)
    # send value
    connection.send(value)
 
# ping pong between processes
def pingpong(connection, send_first):
    print('Process Running', flush=True)
    # check if this process should seed the process
    if send_first:
        generate_send(connection, 0)
    # run until limit reached
    while True:
        # read a value
        value = connection.recv()
        # report
        print(f'>received {value}', flush=True)
        # send the value back
        generate_send(connection, value)
        # check for stop
        if value > 10:
            break
    print('Process Done', flush=True)
 
# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the pipe
    conn1, conn2 = Pipe(duplex=True)
    # create players
    player1 = Process(target=pingpong, args=(conn1,True))
    player2 = Process(target=pingpong, args=(conn2,False))
    # start players
    player1.start()
    player2.start()
    # wait for players to finish
    player1.join()
    player2.join()
```

Source: [Multiprocessing Pipe in Python](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pipe-in-python/)

Comment: can you add more clarity to conn1,conn2 and duplex

Comment: You can use duplex to have equal connections (Not main, auxiliary). So, you can send information from connection1 to connection2 and vice versa.

Comment: how to derive connection class from Process?

Comment: Another Question is how to hold a worker process for infinite time Instead of while loop is there any statergy

Comment: How To Run A Process For Infinite Time Waiting ?